# Verify logical shift left << from AVR Assembler document

Tags: atmega

I am learning the logical operators, I want to confirm the doc is not correct. This is the copy from the doc:

*Symbol: <<
Description: Binary operator, which returns the **left** expression shifted left the number given by the **right** expression.
Example: **ldi r17,1<<bitmask ;Load r17 with 1 shifted left bitmask times****

My understanding is: **bitmask** is the right expression and **1** is the left expression.

So it should be written as:
Binary operator, which returns the **right** expression shifted left the number given by the **left** expression.

Tell me whether I am correct, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original description in the documentation is correct. Your modification is incorrect.

The result is the left expression, left shifted by the number of bits specified in the right expression.

```
result = left << right

e.g.

64 (b1000000) = 1 (b1) << 6
48 (b1100000) = 3 (b11) << 5
6 (b110) = 3 (b11) << 1

etc.
```

Comment: I got it wrong, thanks